# How to make child categories recognize parent's template displays

Tags: categories, children, template-hierarchy

I'm using the Default Post Type `post` for various purposes. To sort them I'm using different categories. And I'm designing different category layout using the slug preference, like: `category-book.php`, `category-notice.php` etc., and everything was just fine.

But just a moment ago found that, any subcategory of the parent category 'book' is redirecting to `index.php` (or `archive.php`, or `category.php`) because they are not recognizing their parent's category template (`category-book.php`), because their slug is different.

How can I make the child categories recognize their parent's template design?
Do I have to make a custom template using a `WP_Query()` for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @Rarst for guiding me to the right direction. Using his direction I googled again and again and found a blog article of WerdsWords with an excellent bit of code snippet filtered to `category_template` as Rarst suggested me, and the good news is: it worked for my cause:

```
function new_subcategory_hierarchy() { 
    $category = get_queried_object();

    $parent_id = $category->category_parent;

    $templates = array();

    if ( $parent_id == 0 ) {
        // Use default values from get_category_template()
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->term_id}.php";
        $templates[] = 'category.php';     
    } else {
        // Create replacement $templates array
        $parent = get_category( $parent_id );

        // Current first
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->term_id}.php";

        // Parent second
        $templates[] = "category-{$parent->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "category-{$parent->term_id}.php";
        $templates[] = 'category.php'; 
    }
    return locate_template( $templates );
}

add_filter( 'category_template', 'new_subcategory_hierarchy' );
```

Link to the article:

- [**Force sub-categories to use the parent category template**](http://werdswords.com/force-sub-categories-use-the-parent-category-template/) — werdswords.com

Comment: Why this is not a default setting I will never know! Thanks very much for this.

Answer (score 2):

The category archive branch of template hierarchy only operates on actual category queried.

If you take a look at [`get_category_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_category_template/) it doesn't look up hierarchy.

You can use `category_template` filter (named dynamically from `{$type}_template` further down the chain) to adjust the choice as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me to the right direction. With your suggestion what I found is mentioned as another Answer. But hesitating actually which one to accept, because your Answer was the pioneer, but that answer is with the exact pin-point solution. :(

Comment: @MayeenulIslam always accept the answer that is closest and _most_ helpful to solving your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the @Rarst sugestion, I needed the function to use the top-level parent template.

```
function new_subcategory_hierarchy() { 
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $parent_id = $category->category_parent;

    // Create replacement $templates array
    $templates = array();

    if ( $parent_id == 0 ) {
        // Use default values from get_category_template()
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";
        $templates[] = "category-{$category->term_id}.php";
        $templates[] = 'category.php';     
    } else {
        // Start from the current term
        $parent = get_category($parent_id);
```

So I add this here:

```
        // Climb up the hierarchy until we reach a term with parent = '0'
        while($parent->parent != '0'){
           $term_id = $parent->parent;
           $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $category->taxonomy);
        }
```

Ending:

```
       // Current first
       $templates[] = "category-{$category->slug}.php";
       $templates[] = "category-{$category->term_id}.php";

       // Parent second
       $templates[] = "category-{$parent->slug}.php";
       $templates[] = "category-{$parent->term_id}.php";
       $templates[] = 'category.php'; 
  }
  return locate_template( $templates );
}                
add_filter( 'category_template', 'new_subcategory_hierarchy' );
```